# How would I go about retrieving a JSON encoded PHP echo to an AJAX script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm looking to retrieve PHP echo's for a registration form to an AJAX script which prevents the page from refreshing. I've looked through a fair few tutorials and none of them seem to be covering my needs.

Being an AJAX / JSON newbie I was hoping I could get some pointers in the right direction.

The registration form consists of a variety of variables such as ($first_name), ($last_name) also, however this is an example of what I'm looking to retrieve as all of the echo's are in a similar format:

```
if (strlen($_POST['username']) < 2){
        {
            echo "Invalid username, must be at least 3 characters.";
            exit;
        }};

        if (strlen($_POST['username']) > 25){
    echo "Invalid username, must be no more than 24 characters.";
    exit;
    }

    if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 5){
        echo "Invalid password, must be at least 5 characters.";
        exit;
        }

        if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 32){
        echo "Invalid password, must be a maximum of 32 characters.";
        exit;
        }
```

I originally tried:

I originally had something like this but I wasn't sure how to apply it:

```
json_encode(array("error"=>1, "message"=>"I suck at AJAX."));
```

However scrapped it after struggling to create an AJAX script to correspond.

Comment: there is no json being output, just text. SHow the ajax code you are trying to retrieve this with

Comment: I've scrapped the AJAX code that I was working with. I'd only started recently and tied myself in a knot. I was just hoping I could steal some knowledge on the matter.

Comment: Why don't you do this validation in the browser instead of once it gets to the server?  You could even restrict those input fields to only allow a max of 25 or 32 characters and highlight red when the moved to another field with the first being too small.

Answer (score 1):

I refactored your code:

```
$status ="";
if (strlen($_POST['username']) <= 3){
    $status = "Invalid username, must be at least 3 characters.";
} else if (strlen($_POST['username']) > 24){
    $status = "Invalid username, must be no more than 24 characters.";
} else if (strlen($_POST['password']) <= 5){
    $status = "Invalid password, must be at least 5 characters.";
} else if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 32){
    $status = "Invalid password, must be a maximum of 32 characters.";
} else {
    $status = "ok";
}

echo json_encode(array('status' => $status));
```

jquery script:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'username: "hello", password : "hello2"} ,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.status);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Probably, I would code it differently, but this is based on your code. Good luck.

Comment: If I was to encode each of the echo's with JSON individually, could you possibly show me what the AJAX script would look like to display them without page refresh?

I'll quickly edit the post to show you guys what I _did_ have.

Comment: this is the ajax.php script. in order to call it without refresh, I use jquery

Comment: I included the javascript (jquery)) code If you still have an issue understanding how ajax works, please read these follow links: 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/

Comment: Getting a Bosh and never come back. That is cold!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which will handle that for you though : Example below :

```
function json_alert($alert_type,$alert_msg) {

    ob_end_clean(); //this will removing any previous output, very important because json will be invalid with other output

    echo json_encode  (array(
        "alert_type" => $alert_type, 
        "alert_msg" => $alert_msg
    ));

    exit(); //required too,this ends execution
}
```

Now that we have our function, You can call it like :

```
    if (strlen($_POST['username']) < 2) {
        json_alert("error","Invalid username, must be at least 3 characters.");   
    }

    if (strlen($_POST['username']) > 25) {
        json_alert("error","Invalid username, must be no more than 24 characters.");
    }

    if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 5) {
        json_alert("error","Invalid password, must be at least 5 characters.");
    }

    if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 32) {
        json_alert("error","Invalid password, must be a maximum of 32 characters.");
    }
```

Now in Jquery , This is how you will go about it

```
$.ajax({
    dataType : "json",// we need json back
    data : $("form").serialize(),//get form data
    url: "http://url-of-login-processor",
    type : "POST" // Either POST or GET method
}).done(function(callback) {
    if(callback.alert_type =="error") {
        //what to do if error
    }else{
        //what to do if success
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You for the formatting changes , I am not used to stackoverflow's form stuff.